# Why can the determinant of a transformation matrix, and the original are be used to find out the new area?

Tags: matrices, area

Im studying Year 11 Mathematical Methods. Within the book there are several questions which give vertices (or sometimes just the area) of a particular shap, plus a transformation matrix to be applied to it. After coming across a particulalry bizzare shape that I could not work out the area for, I backtracked (got the answer courtesy of BOB) trying to find a way to get to the answer (Ill post the question below).

What I found was that when I took the determinant of the matrix $T$ (transformation) and multiplied it by the original area, I attained the area of the new shape. I wish to know why this is.

Note: I don't even know if you can have transformation matricies larger than 2x2, but this only concerns 2x2 matrices.

Question one

A rectangle ABCD is transformed under the transformation matrix $T = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 2 \\ 5 & 8 \end{pmatrix}$ to give vertices at A′(0, 0), B′(3, 0), C′(3, 2) and D′(0, 2). Calculate the area of the transformed figure ABCD (although this is technicaly the ORIGINAL shape).

Area of 3/7 units

Question Two

The triangle ABC is mapped by the transformation represented by $T = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & −1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$ onto the triangle A′B′C′. Given that the area of ABC is 10 units, find the area of A′B′C′.

Area of 70 units

Comment: You can make the formatting nicer using MathJax (there's an environment called bmatrix that looks nice for this). Anyway, the basic idea is that if you put the unit square into T, you get a parallelogram which is described by the two columns of T. The area of this parallelogram is the determinant (this is the interesting part). The area of the square you started with was 1. So the area got multiplied by the determinant.

Comment: Now you can break up whatever shape you have into small squares, and each one will get mapped to a small parallelogram the same way the unit square did. Each square will get its area multiplied by the determinant, so the total area will get multiplied by the determinant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a unit square generated by the vectors $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. Then, the parallelogram that the vectors transformed by a matrix $T = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}$ is that generated by the vectors:
$$(1,0)\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix} = ( a, b)$$
$$(0,1)\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix} = (c,d)$$
and therefore, its area is $ad - bc = det(T)$.

Since any vectors that generate a rectangle is a linear combination of $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$, the area of any rectangle is distorted in the same way by a transformation $T$ and all we need is the determinant of the matrix.